# How to get hyperlink in a formula using EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, epplus

I need to get the exact link inside the formula(HYPERLINK) and save it to the database. here is my code to get the link,

```cs
answerList.Add(new SurveyCompetitorAnswer
{

    MainSurveyId = id,
    Answer = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Text,
    DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
    Link = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Formula,
    SurveyQuestionId = item.Id,
    SurveyCompetitorId = comp.Id
});
```

but it get the whole FORMULA text. 
example (HYPERLINK("https://www.owler.com/company/sproutsolutions","0.5"))

...

what I need is just https://www.owler.com/company/sproutsolutions.

I tried using `Link = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Hyperlink,` but its purpose is only to SET links and not GET links.

EDIT: I tried using `var link = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange];` and `Link = link.Hyperlink.AbsoluteUri`, but it shows null reference exception

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did instead.

```
   var link = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Formula;
   int index = link.IndexOf(",");
   if (index > 0)
   {
      link = link.Substring(0, index);
   }
   var onemore = link.Substring(11);
   var final = onemore.Substring(0,onemore.Length -1);

   answerList.Add(new SurveyCompetitorAnswer
   {
      MainSurveyId = id,
      Answer = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Text,
      DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
      Link = final,
      SurveyQuestionId = item.Id,
      SurveyCompetitorId = comp.Id
   });
```

working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like being able to take the formula `HYPERLINK("https://www.owler.com/company/sproutsolutions","0.5")` and extract the part `...` within `("...",` is what you want. So you need a way to read and extract a sub-string from a string (in this case the formula is the string, and the URL is the sub-string).

I'm not an expert in this by any means, but would one of these help?

[Epplus read hyperlink with html fragment i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970864/epplus-read-hyperlink-with-html-fragment-i)

[How to extract link url from Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727557/how-to-extract-link-url-from-excel-cell)

[Extracting a URL from hyperlinked text in Excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646549/extracting-a-url-from-hyperlinked-text-in-excel-cell/5797075)

***A note to future readers:**
The author of the original question posted her own solution. Her method does work, but **only** when the the contents of the cell containing the hyperlink contains the formula `HYPERLINK("URL","YourFriendlyNameGoesHere")` and has  **no spaces** before the `"URL"` in `HYPERLINK("URL",....)` like in the situation: `HYPERLINK(    "URL",....)`, which could result from spaces being accidentally typed into the cell (even just one space could be an issue).

This situation can be remedied by using the method `.IndexOf("\"")` to find the first quotation mark's `"` index position, instead of simply using `.Substring(11)`, which assumes the position index 11 in `HYPERLINK("URL",....)` is the beginning of `URL`, which may not be the case when there's an extra space. Instead, use `.Substring(...)` with the index position of `"` + 1 in place of `...` as the argument to `.Substring(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried using the second link `Link = workSheet.Cells[AnswerRowRange].Hyperlink.AbsoluteUri,` but it shows a null reference.

Comment: @ChrisMay Correct, as you mentioned in your original post, ```.Hyperlink``` is used to set links, not get links. So ```.Hyperlink.AbsoluteUri``` wouldn't have to do with getting links.  Do you know of a way to search a string? Because if you could search the string that is produced from the ```.Formula``` method, then you could extract just the hyperlink. Correct me if I'm wrong, but are you using C# language?

Comment: @ChrisMay Here is a work-around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10709821/find-text-in-string-with-c-sharp  Use the answer here to extract ```URL``` within ```HYPERLINK("URL",".........```

Comment: Yes, C#. I Tried using substring(11), it gets the start of the link but it gets the rest of the formula. Example `https://sprout.ph/about/","2015")`.

Comment: As long as the ```URL``` doesn't contain a ```("``` then you should be fine. Otherwise this workaround may not work. I'm not certain, however.

Comment: Further, this may be useful: https://github.com/spreadsheetlab/XLParser

It parses/analyzes an excel formula and breaks it up into all of its individual parts.

You can see with this demonstration of it: http://xlparser.perfectxl.nl/demo/